# Angular application compiled successfully but isn't loaded in the browser, also throwing Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

Tags: java, angular, versionupgrade

I upgraded my Angular application from Angular 11 to Angular 12, after a lot of work I finally solved all the errors and the application was compiling successfully. But now when I open the local server to take a look at it, it doesn't display anything on the screen .
Error Coming in console is below .

```
util.js:109 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Object.MCLT (util.js:109:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84:1)
    at yz4/ (dropdown-menu.component.ts:9:35)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84:1)
    at Dwu+ (environment.ts:16:68)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84:1)
    at Module.ZAI4 (main.js:3680:94)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84:1)
    at Module.zUnb (main.ts:1:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84:1)
```

Can someone help me out  to Load the application on browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried deleting your node_modules folder and package-lock.json and run:

```
npm install
```

Another fix that might work would be:

```
npm link webpack
```